# There is no last entered value taken from dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, text-files, txt

```cs
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"file.txt", FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(fs);

try
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1 ; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            streamwriter.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value + "#");
        }

        streamwriter.WriteLine("\n");
    }

    streamwriter.Close();
    fs.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("File saved successfully!");
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("File save failed!");
}
```

This function should transfer the values ​​from the `DataGridView` to the file but the last value is not constantly written. I realized that it deletes the last element I entered

It should be like this:

> `Name1#Lastname1#Number1#Home1#`

This is real result:

> `Name2#Lastname2#Number2##`

Comment: Tested your code, and everything works fine. Did you miss some steps to reproduce the issue? Where did you execute the code? Via a button click? Or any datagridview event?

Comment: MenuStrip .I realized that it deletes the last element I entered

Comment: change your first loop condition from `dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1` to `dataGridView1.Rows.Count`

Comment: It does the same, but adds another empty row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code will work “IF” the `DataGridView’s` property `AllowUsersToAddRows` is set to `true`. If it is set to `false`, then, the posted code is going to miss the last row in the grid.

In addition, depending on the grids `DataSource`, the data source itself may not allow new rows or be structured to add new rows. In this case, the `AllowUsersToAddRows` property becomes irrelevant, however in either case… the posted code will still miss the last row.

Since the code is technically correct “IF” the grid’s `AllowUsersToAddRows` property is set to `true`. And, your question appears to be about the “missing” last row… I would assume that either the grids `AllowUsersToAddRows` property is set to `false` or the data source does not allow adding new rows.

To avoid this issue… I suggest an extra check for this “new” row in the row loop. If you check for the “new” row in the row loop, then it will not matter if the grids `AllowUsersToAddRows` property is `true` or `false`. Also using a `foreach` loop through the rows and cells may make things easier and may look something like…

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
  if (!row.IsNewRow) {
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
      streamwriter.Write(cell.Value + "#");
    }
    streamwriter.WriteLine("");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your loop iterating over rows, right now your condition is

`j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1`

This means if the row count is 10, your loop will go through indexes 0 to 8, and skip index 9.

You should change your condition to

`j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count`

Comment: It does the same, but adds another empty row.